# How do I pass an id variable to a class which has dependency injection Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have class that uses Dependency Injection, with two other classes, this works fine.  But I want to then instantiate the Merchant class in a controller and pass an id . Thing I don't get is the constructor is expecting more values 'CurrencyConverter' and 'TransactionTable' so how can I complete the code ? ?, which I don't need to pass.  So I'm not clear how to make it work, thanks

Model Class

```
namespace TransactionBundle\Model;

class Merchant
{
public $_transactions;
public $_currencyConverter;
public $_id;

public function __construct($id,CurrencyConverter                    
    $currencyConverter,TransactionTable $transactions)
{
    $this->_transactions = $transactions;
    $this->_currencyConverter = $currencyConverter;
    $this->_id = $id;

}

public function getTransactions() {

    $this->_currencyConverter->convert();

    $this->_transactions->getData();       

}
```

}

```
trying to instantiate in the controller

$merchant = new Merchant(2,?,?);

$results = $merchant->getTransactions();
```

Comment: The new operator knows nothing about the Symfony di container.  You would have to pass the dependency yourself.  What you probably want is to define a MerchantFactory service and inject it into your controller.  You might then do something like $merchant = $merchantFactory->create($id);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class has a dependency on something that is not in the container, then the class cannot be loaded from the container.

Either pass the dependencies yourself in the controller:

```
$merchant = new Merchant(2, $currencyConverter, $transactions);
```

Or use a factory service in the container:

```
class MerchantFactory {
    private $currencyConverter;
    private $transactions;

    // constructor omitted for brevity

    public function getMerchantForId($id) {
        return new Merchant($id, $this->currencyConverter, $this->transactions);
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, depend on the factory:

```
$merchant = $this->merchantFactory->getMerchantForId(2);
```

Comment: In the 1st and 2nd option I have to add - $this->currencyConverter = new CurrencyConverter();
    $this->transactions = new TransactionTable();